# resolving file path within a function

Tags: asp.net

I have a function which works in the development environment but I need to change the path so it resolves properly at the host servers.

This code line;

```
doc.Load("H:\Website_Sep2012\OtherDataFiles\dataXML.xml") 'this needs to be changed to the server path
```

within this function

```
Public Shared Function GetList(ByVal nodestring As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()

    'Load XML from the file into XmlDocument object
    doc.Load("H:\Website_Sep2012\OtherDataFiles\dataXML.xml") 'this needs to be changed to the server path
    Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement

    'Select all nodes with the tag paramter indicated by the nodestring variable
    Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes(nodestring)
    Return (From node As XmlNode In nodeList Select node.InnerText).ToList()
End Function
```

Replacing the string with `Server.MapPath("~/OtherDataFiles\dataXML.xml")` does not work as Server is not available in that scope. Any ideas how to resolve this path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try:

[System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx) No need for `HttpContext`

OR

```
using System.Web;

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/OtherDataFiles/dataXML.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

The Server can always be reached like this:

```
string filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/OtherDataFiles/dataXML.xml");
doc.Load(filePath);
```

If inside a class library project you can just add reference to System.Web assembly.